# use firebase Storage with Admin sdk node.js

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-admin

I want to use firebase storage by using admin SDK, Because using gcd need paid account.

I tried a lot to use gcd without a paid account but I didn't find a way to do that in addition to using gcd storage was complicated.

I tried to find answers in firebase documentation but mentioned functions documentation doesn't work at all.
so I decided to post the answer to this problem so it could help other people

Answer (score 5):

after all, I found a way to use  admin SDK to use firebase storage to upload and download files

first, you should install firebase-admin

> npm install --save firebase-admin

I don't remember if you have to install @firebase/storage or not

let's take about code 
first you have to initiate

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var firebase = require("firebase");
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/your/private/ket.json");
```

the private key is generated from firebaseConsole

> firebaseConsole->project Settings->service account ->generate private key

now you can use firebase bucket

```
admin.initializeApp({
credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
storageBucket: "{storageBucket}"
});
var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();
```

you can find storageBucket here beside {upload file} button

[image]

now let take how to upload pictures to my folder named pic 'you can use it without making any sub-folders'

```
uploadPic (picName, Picture) => {

db.bucket.upload(Picture.path, {
    destination: "pic/" + picName,
    metadata: {
        contentType: Picture.mimetype,
        cacheControl: 'public, max-age=31536000'
    }
}, (err, file) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    } else {
        console.log('done');
    }
    return;
});
};
```

you need to send all file to this function or path to your picture and mimetype there is necessary information, you need too to send id so if you search for it so you can find it.

this code used to get picture URL

```
let baseUrl = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/'+'{storageBucket }'+'/o/'+'{folderName}'+'%2F';

getPicUrl (pictureName) => {
db.bucket.getFiles({ prefix: 'pic/' + pictureName}).then((file) => {
    var token = file[0][0].metadata.metadata.firebaseStorageDownloadTokens;
    baseUrl = baseUrl + pictureName+ '?alt=media&token=' + token;
    return;
}).catch((err) => {
    console.log(err.message);
});
return baseUrl;
};
```

this function will return download URL that you can use it to show this file or downloaded it

that all I know I tried to explain it in the best way I can I hope you like it

Good Luck :)

Comment: could you share github or something? Im seaching for exactly this and trying to adapt it for next.js

Comment: this is my github link if you still didnt find solution for your problem https://github.com/kerolosFawzy/Gp if you still didnt find solution message me